# I am trying to get data from database using python Django but got an error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-database, django-errors

Hello everyone I am trying to get data from database but it give me error in case when I am trying to get single data from db as shown below

```
wahid = Webapp.objects.get(title="Ecommerce Website")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 418, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1258, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1084, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "C:\Users\wahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1481, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'title' into field. Choices are: created, demo_link, description, id, review, source_link, tags, tiltle, vote_ratio, vote_total
```

[It will work only on getting all data from db as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlRpl.png)

Comment: The model field is named "tiltle" not "title"?

Comment: Does your **Webapp** model contain **title** attribute

Comment: Thank you so much  it was a spelling mistake and now it's resolved

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake,
You have created field name "**tiltle**" in models, however you are trying to fetch "**title**" in your get query

Also, using **get** query might throw an error if there are more than one record that have title="Ecommerce Website"

for that you can use

```
 Webapp.objects.filter(title="Ecommerce Website")
```

Comment: yeah it was spelling mistake thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you should rename title field in your model, it seems you enter title field name to wrong dictation

'tiltle' must be 'title' in your model

Comment: Yes I rename the title field correctly and it's work thank you